# How do I write multi-line queries in KDB?

Tags: kdb

Currently, my query is expanding, and only getting longer:

```
m: ungroup select date, c, prevClose: prev c, prevVolume: prev v, premarketGap: log[o % prev c], t1Range: log[(prev h)%(prev o)], t1Return: t1Log[c], t5Return: tXreturn[5;1;c], t25Return: tXreturn[25;6;c], t250Return: tXreturn[250;31;c], targetH: log[h%o], targetL: log[l%o], targetC: log[c%o] by sym from daily;
```

I've tried breaking it up into multiple lines with `;` and indents, but it doesn't seem to like it no matter what I do.

I'm using KX Developer as an interface.

How do I break up queries into multiple lines?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [q/kdb: How do I break my code into lines. Is there a new line 'escape' character or something similar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44332272/q-kdb-how-do-i-break-my-code-into-lines-is-there-a-new-line-escape-character)

Comment: I tried this to begin with, and I get 'badly formed select statement'. I cannot find any examples in the documentation either of multiline being valid code.

Comment: Please do add the [mre] with the complete error message (in TEXT) to this question (using [edit]).  Now one can only guess what you are actually doing.

Answer (score 2):

If you are writing multi-line queries in a `.q` file you need at least one space on each of the following line(s) for the query to execute. i.e.

```
m:ungroup select date, c, prevClose: prev c, 
  prevVolume: prev v, premarketGap: log[o % prev c], 
  t1Range: log[(prev h)%(prev o)], t1Return: t1Log[c], 
  t5Return: tXreturn[5;1;c], t25Return: tXreturn[25;6;c], 
  t250Return: tXreturn[250;31;c], targetH: log[h%o], 
  targetL: log[l%o], targetC: log[c%o] 
    by sym from daily;
```

(I indented again for the `by` clause as this is easier to read and follows recommended SQL syntax).

Comment: Alas I get the error: `from: Badly formed select statement` - screenshot here: https://imgur.com/a/tnSasLX

Comment: may be a silly question but does the query execute when on a single line?

Comment: Yes it does; it's just getting unwieldy as the query is several screens across! I can't find any evidence in the docs that multi-line queries are even possible.

Comment: Since this is a kx product I would advise posting in the kx community for help: https://community.kx.com/